# Ошибка Notice: Undefined index

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой :(

> Notice: Undefined index: status in /home/c/cg18258/public_html/wp-content/plugins/premiumbox/default/moduls.php on line 282

moduls.php

```
    <?php
if( !defined( 'ABSPATH')){ exit(); }

add_action('pn_adminpage_title_pn_moduls', 'def_adminpage_title_pn_moduls');
function def_adminpage_title_pn_moduls($page){
    _e('Modules','pn');
} 

add_action('pn_adminpage_content_pn_moduls','def_pn_adminpage_content_pn_moduls');
function def_pn_adminpage_content_pn_moduls(){

    if(class_exists('pn_moduls_List_Table')){ 
        $Table = new pn_moduls_List_Table();
        $Table->prepare_items();

        $search = array();

        $list = pn_list_extended('moduls');
        $cats = array('0'=>'--'. __('All categories','pn') .'--');
        foreach($list as $data){
            $c = is_extension_name($data['cat']);
            $n = pn_strip_input(ctv_ml($data['category']));
            if($c and $n){
                $cats[$c] = $n;
            }
        }

        $search[] = array(
            'view' => 'select',
            'options' => $cats,
            'title' => __('Module categories','pn'),
            'default' => is_extension_name(is_param_get('cat')),
            'name' => 'cat',
        );
        $placed = array(
            '0' => '--'. __('All locations','pn') .'--',
            'plugin' => __('Plugin','pn'),
            'theme' => __('Theme','pn'),
        );
        $search[] = array(
            'view' => 'select',
            'options' => $placed,
            'title' => __('Module locations','pn'),
            'default' => is_extension_name(is_param_get('place')),
            'name' => 'place',
        );      
        pn_admin_searchbox($search, 'reply');       
?>
    <style>
    .column-title{ width: 200px!important; }
    </style>

    <?php 
    $options = array();
    $options['mod'] = array(
        'name' => 'mod',
        'options' => array(
            '1' => __('active moduls','pn'),
            '2' => __('inactive moduls','pn'),
        ),
        'title' => '',
    );
    pn_admin_submenu($options, 'reply');    
    ?>  

    <form method="post" action="<?php pn_the_link_post(); ?>">
        <?php $Table->display(); ?>
    </form>
<?php 
    } else {
        echo 'Class not found';
    }
} 

add_action('premium_action_pn_moduls','def_premium_action_pn_moduls');
function def_premium_action_pn_moduls(){
global $wpdb, $premiumbox;  

    only_post();
    pn_only_caps(array('administrator'));

    $reply = '';
    $action = get_admin_action();

    if(isset($_POST['id']) and is_array($_POST['id'])){
        if($action == 'active'){

            $extended = get_option('pn_extended');
            if(!is_array($extended)){ $extended = array(); }

            foreach($_POST['id'] as $id){
                $id = is_extension_name($id);
                if($id){
                    if(!isset($extended['moduls'][$id])){
                        $extended['moduls'][$id] = $id;

                        pn_include_extanded('moduls', $id);

                        do_action('pn_moduls_active_'.$id);
                        do_action('pn_moduls_active', $id);
                    }
                }   
            }
            update_option('pn_extended', $extended);
            $premiumbox->plugin_create_pages();

            $reply = '&reply=true';     
        }

        if($action == 'deactive'){

            $extended = get_option('pn_extended');
            if(!is_array($extended)){ $extended = array(); }

            foreach($_POST['id'] as $id){
                $id = is_extension_name($id);
                if($id){
                    if(isset($extended['moduls'][$id])){
                        unset($extended['moduls'][$id]);
                        do_action('pn_moduls_deactive_'.$id);
                        do_action('pn_moduls_deactive', $id);
                    }
                }   
            }
            update_option('pn_extended', $extended);

            $reply = '&reply=true';     
        }               
    }

    $ref = is_param_post('_wp_http_referer');
    $ref = pn_admin_filter_data($ref, 'reply, paged');
    $paged = intval(is_param_post('paged'));
    if($paged > 1){ $ref .= '&paged='.$paged; }         
    $url = $ref . $reply;
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;           
} 

add_action('premium_action_pn_moduls_activate','def_premium_action_pn_moduls_activate');
function def_premium_action_pn_moduls_activate(){
global $wpdb, $premiumbox;

    pn_only_caps(array('administrator'));   

    $id = is_extension_name(is_param_get('key'));   
    if($id){

        $extended = get_option('pn_extended');
        if(!is_array($extended)){ $extended = array(); }

        if(!isset($extended['moduls'][$id])){
            $extended['moduls'][$id] = $id;

            pn_include_extanded('moduls', $id);

            do_action('pn_moduls_active_'. $id);
            do_action('pn_moduls_active', $id);
        }   

        update_option('pn_extended', $extended);
        $premiumbox->plugin_create_pages();
    }

    $ref = is_param_get('_wp_http_referer');
    $url = pn_admin_filter_data($ref, 'reply').'reply=true';
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;       
}

add_action('premium_action_pn_moduls_deactivate','def_premium_action_pn_moduls_deactivate');
function def_premium_action_pn_moduls_deactivate(){
global $wpdb;   

    pn_only_caps(array('administrator'));   

    $id = is_extension_name(is_param_get('key'));   
    if($id){

        $extended = get_option('pn_extended');
        if(!is_array($extended)){ $extended = array(); }

        if(isset($extended['moduls'][$id])){
            unset($extended['moduls'][$id]);

            do_action('pn_moduls_deactive_'. $id);
            do_action('pn_moduls_deactive', $id);
        }   

        update_option('pn_extended', $extended);

    }

    $ref = is_param_get('_wp_http_referer');
    $url = pn_admin_filter_data($ref, 'reply').'reply=true';
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}   

class pn_moduls_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    function __construct(){
        global $status, $page;

        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular'  => 'id',      
            'ajax' => false,  
        ) );

    }

    function column_default($item, $column_name){

        if($column_name == 'descr'){
            $html = '
                <div>'. pn_strip_input(ctv_ml($item['description'])) .'</div>
                <div class="active second plugin-version-author-uri">'. __('Version','pn') .': '. pn_strip_input($item['version']) .'</div>
            ';

            return $html;
        } elseif($column_name == 'category'){   
            return '<a href="'. admin_url('admin.php?page=pn_moduls&cat='. is_isset($item, 'cat')) .'&place='. is_param_get('place') .'&mod='. is_param_get('mod') .'">'. pn_strip_input(ctv_ml($item['category'])) . '</a>';
        } elseif($column_name == 'place'){  
            $place = __('Plugin','pn');
            if(is_isset($item, 'place') == 'theme'){
                $place = __('Theme','pn');
            }
            return '<a href="'. admin_url('admin.php?page=pn_moduls&place='. is_isset($item, 'place')) .'&cat='. is_param_get('cat') .'&mod='. is_param_get('mod') .'">'. $place . '</a>';      
        } elseif($column_name == 'dependent'){  
            return pn_strip_input($item['dependent']);
        } elseif($column_name == 'name'){   
            $name = is_extension_name($item['name']);
            $name = str_replace('_theme','', $name);
            return $name;
        }

    }   

    function column_cb($item){
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
            $this->_args['singular'], 
            $item['name']                
        );
    }   

    function column_title($item){

        if($item['status'] == 'active'){
            $actions['deactive']  = '<a href="'. pn_link_post('pn_moduls_deactivate', 'post') . '&key=' . $item['name'] . '&_wp_http_referer=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .'">'. __('Deactivate','pn') .'</a>';
        } else {
            $actions['active']  = '<a href="'. pn_link_post('pn_moduls_activate', 'post') . '&key=' . $item['name'] . '&_wp_http_referer=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) .'">'. __('Activate','pn') .'</a>';
        }

        return sprintf('%1$s %2$s',
            '<strong>'. pn_strip_input(ctv_ml($item['title'])) .'</strong>',
            $this->row_actions($actions)
        );

    }   

    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
            'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title'     => __('Title','pn'),
            'descr'     => __('Description','pn'),
            'category'     => __('Category','pn'),
            'place'     => __('Location','pn'),
            'name'     => __('Folder name','pn'),
            'dependent'     => __('Dependent modules','pn'),
        );

        return $columns;
    }   

    function get_primary_column_name() {
        return 'title';
    }

    function single_row( $item ) {
        $class = '';
        if($item['status'] == 'active'){
            $class = 'active';
        }
        echo '<tr class="pn_tr '. $class .'">';
            $this->single_row_columns( $item );
        echo '</tr>';
    }       

    function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = array(
            'active'    => __('Activate','pn'),
            'deactive'    => __('Deactivate','pn'),
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb; 

        $per_page = $this->get_items_per_page('pn_moduls_per_page', 50);
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();

        $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();
        $offset = ($current_page-1)*$per_page;

        $list = pn_list_extended('moduls');
        $ndata = array();
        $mod = intval(is_param_get('mod'));
        $cat = is_extension_name(is_param_get('cat'));
        $place = is_extension_name(is_param_get('place'));

        foreach($list as $list_key => $list_value){
            $module_status = $list_value['status'];
            $module_category = is_extension_name($list_value['cat']);
            $module_place = $list_value['place'];

            $show = 0;

            if($mod == 1){
                if($module_status == 'active'){
                    $show = 1;
                }
            } elseif($mod == 2){
                if($module_status == 'deactive'){
                    $show = 1;
                }           
            } else {
                $show = 1;
            }

            if($cat){
                if($module_category != $cat){
                    $show = 0;
                }
            }

            if($place){
                if($module_place != $place){
                    $show = 0;
                }
            }           

            if($show == 1){
                $ndata[] = $list_value;
            }
        }   

        $data = $ndata;
        $items = array_slice($data,$offset,$per_page);

        $total_items = count($data);
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $this->items = $items;

        $this->set_pagination_args( array(
            'total_items' => $total_items,                  
            'per_page'    => $per_page,                     
            'total_pages' => ceil($total_items/$per_page)  
        ));
    }   

} 

add_action('premium_screen_pn_moduls','my_premium_screen_pn_moduls');
function my_premium_screen_pn_moduls() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Display','pn'),
        'default' => 50,
        'option' => 'pn_moduls_per_page'
    );
    add_screen_option('per_page', $args );  

    if(class_exists('pn_moduls_List_Table')){
        new pn_moduls_List_Table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычно notice не является проблемой. Зачем вам её исправлять? И зачем весь этот длинный код? Укажите, в какой строке ошибка.

Comment: у меня не включаются модули в WordPress и я включил Debug режим и получил ошибки... Я думаю что в этом дело. После нажатия на кнопку "Активировать" ничего не происходит.

Comment: Версию php подними

Comment: Версия php v7.2